# Express-Validator issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am facing an issue with express-validator, when I use its body validation like `body('email').isEmail()` or any type of validation then after that VS Code don't show me any suggestions.

```
    router.post('/register', [
    body('email').isEmail(),
    body('password', 'Password must be 7 characters long').isLength({ min: 7 })
], (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

});
```

when I use `[]` to create an array of body validation then vs code stop giving me suggestion and if I remove those `[]` then I can't use suggestion on validations.
**When I use `[]`** :
When I type `res.s` then I should get suggestion/ emmet like send, status etc. but I don't get any.
**When I don't use `[]`** :
When I type `body('email').` I should get suggestions / emmet like `isEmail()`, `isLength()` etc. but I don't receive any emmet.

My `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.9"
  }
```

Anyone have any idea.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the below link. In the example show in this link they are not using [] brackets

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :) IDK what was wrong I have checked their docs but last time it didn't worked for me, I  just received an update from VS Code and it working fine. Thanks